# Fastify plugin fastify-autoload error plugin must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I have setup the fastify framework with fastify-cli library with command `fastify-cli generate`. It has fastify-autoload plugin used out of the box.

But, it will throw an error when I add my own service with exception for model.js and schema.js files.

```
...
fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'services'),
    options: Object.assign({}, opts),
    ignorePattern: /.*(model|schema)\.js/
})
...
```

Error message:

```
assert.js:788
    throw newErr;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: plugin must be a function
    at wrap (D:\project\kuisioner\backend\node_modules\fastify-cli\start.js:124:5)
    ...
      actual: Error: plugin must be a function
    ...
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    ...
```

But it will run smoothly when I register it manually

```
...
fastify.register(require('./services/quiz/get'))
fastify.register(require('./services/quiz/post'))
...
```

My file structure:

```
- src
  - plugins
    - db.js
  - services
  | - quiz
  |   - get.js
  |   - model.js
  |   - post.js
  |   - schema.js
  - app.js
```

I use fastify-cli `fastify start -l info src/app.js` to run my code

Here's my repo https://github.com/nnfans/kuisionerid_backend

Comment: did you try `module.exports.autoload = false` on those file also?

Comment: that's works fine. But why the `ignorePattern: /.*(model|schema)\.js/` isn't working? Does I use it in wrong way?

Comment: I have tried to run `fastify generate ./ && npm i` and then add a model.js and your ignore pattern but it works. I think the problem is that `src/` that you may have added after the generation

Comment: what's your model.js contents?

Comment: it is `module.exports = {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking your repo the error is the `dir` value. You must point to the dir with the files, it is not supported the recursive loading yet

```
  fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'services/quiz'), 
    options: Object.assign({}, opts),
    ignorePattern: /.*(model|schema)\.js/
  })
```

With this change, the `npm start` will work.

Another option is to use `module.exports.autoload = false` in the files that need to be skipped, but your regex is ok.

Answer (score 4):

if you got here and you use typescript, maybe try to delete the dist dir and re-run tsc, you might have had a bad route that persisted there

Answer (score 1):

May be If you have accidentally create a empty route file this issue will happens and it persist on the dist ( Mostly you are using TypeScript ) This empty route file not returning functional output. As yonadav bar ilan said you have to delete dist and try to re-run it.